# MYSQL - Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY'

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a parent table Customers and a child table Addresses. When I created Customers I left ADDRESS reference ID 0 so I could fill it in later. Well now is the time insert the ADDRESSES id's into Customers but when I run the command I get a duplicate error, even though there isn’t any.

```
insert into Customers (ADDRESS) select ID from Addresses ;
ERROR 1062 (23000): Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY'
```

Customers

```
+---------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field   | Type          | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+---------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| ID      | int(11)       | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| NAME    | varchar(20)   | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| AGE     | int(11)       | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| ADDRESS | int(11)       | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| SALARY  | decimal(18,2) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+---------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Addresses

```
+------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| ID         | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| CUSTOMERID | int(11)     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| CITY       | varchar(35) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| COUNTRY    | varchar(45) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
4 rows in set (0.02 sec)
```

Customers

```
+----+--------+-----+---------+---------+
| ID | NAME   | AGE | ADDRESS | SALARY  |
+----+--------+-----+---------+---------+
|  0 | Matt   |  24 |       0 | 2200.00 |
|  1 | Andrew |  23 |       0 | 4400.00 |
|  2 | John   |  30 |       0 | 1200.00 |
|  3 | Mike   |  55 |       0 | 5500.00 |
|  5 | George |  45 |       0 | 2300.00 |
|  6 | Frank  |  32 |       0 | 2300.00 |
|  7 | George |  45 |       0 | 2700.00 |
|  8 | Joe    |  38 |       0 | 4350.00 |
|  9 | Josh   |  35 |       0 | 5050.00 |
+----+--------+-----+---------+---------+
```

Addresses

```
+----+------------+----------+---------+
| ID | CUSTOMERID | CITY     | COUNTRY |
+----+------------+----------+---------+
| 15 |          0 | Chicago  | USA     |
| 16 |          1 | Chicago  | USA     |
| 17 |          2 | London   | ENG     |
| 18 |          3 | New York | USA     |
| 19 |          5 | New York | USA     |
| 20 |          6 | New York | USA     |
| 21 |          7 | Chicago  | USA     |
| 23 |          8 | Miami    | NULL    |
| 25 |          9 | Miami    | NULL    |
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should make the `CustomerId` an auto-increment key in `Customers`.

That is the problem you are facing.  Because you are not giving `Customer.Id` a value in the `insert`, MySQL would tend to assign `NULL`.  But primary keys cannot be `NULL`, so MySQL does you a favor of converting the value to 0.  You then get a conflict on the second insert (if there is already a row with `0` in it).

Comment: Okay so when i do insert its actually creating new rows, how do update it from another table instead ?

Comment: @John . . . Update what?  I think you should ask another question.  The question in your comment seems quite different from the question you have asked.

Answer (score 1):

You should use autoincrement for your customer table

```
`ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
```

otherwise using

insert into Customers (ADDRESS) select ID from Addresses ;

you are trying to insert a new row  (but without a proper id  .. is again 0)

Comment: Gordon was technically first, but you are correct. Thanks